# Binary String to Decimal String

Tags: algorithm, radix

Good afternoon,

How would you go about converting to a decimal string a binary string with more characters than bits in a language's largest integer type? In other words, supposing that you have the string

```
111001101001110100100(...)1001001111011100100
```

and that you can't convert it to an integer first, how would you go about writing it in base 10?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "you can't convert it to an integer first". It **is** an integer, at least, it is the representation of an integer in base 2. If you mean you are looking for a purely **typographical** transformation from the base 2 representation of an integer to the base 10 representation of the same integer, without ever *realising* the integer in question, I think you will be out of luck.

Answer (score 17):

You can use an algorithm like:

```
// X is the input
while ( X != "0" )
  compute X' and R such that X = 10 * X' + R  (Euclidean division, see below)
  output R    // least significant decimal digit first
  X = X'
```

The Euclidean division of X by 10 is computed like this:

```
R = 0  // remainder in 0..9
X' = ""
for (b in bits of X)  // msb to lsb
  R = 2*R + b
  if R >= 10
    X' += "1"
    R -= 10
  else
    X' += "0"

Remove leading "0" from X'
The remainder is R in 0..9
```

Comment: This is a really nice answer. It works for any base, just swap the base (10 in the code above) for something else. For example, use 8 for a binary to octal conversion.

Answer (score 5):

Write your own arithmetic in base 10.  Only addition is needed.  Example implementation in Python:

```
from math import log, ceil

def add(a, b):
    """Add b to a in decimal representation."""
    carry = 0
    for i in range(len(b)):
        carry, a[i] = divmod(a[i] + b[i] + carry, 10)
    while carry:
        i += 1
        carry, a[i] = divmod(a[i] + carry, 10)

# an example string
s = bin(3 ** 120)[2:]

# reserve enough decimal digits
res = [0] * int(ceil(len(s) * log(2) / log(10)))

# convert
for c in s:
    add(res, res)
    if c == "1":
        add(res, [1])

#print output
print str.join("", map(str, reversed(res)))
```

This uses lists of intergers to represent numbers in base 10.  The list items correspond to the digits of the base 10 number.  The item at index 0 corresponds to the ones, the item at index 1 to the tens, and so on.

Comment: If you use Python 3, it has arbitrary-long integers built-in :)

Comment: @9000: Every version of Python has arbitrary precision integers built-in.  I just used Python notation to desrcibe the algorithm.

Comment: Yes, you can always `import decimal`, but in Py3k plain integers migrate to arbitrary precision when needed. BTW, +1 for the explanation.

Comment: @9000: Every version of Python has arbitrary precision integers built-in, long before the advent of the `decimal` module.  The code above is actually using them to generate the example string (`3**120` is to big for machine precision integers).

Answer (score 3):

10 is not a power of 2, thus a digit at any place of a binary representation may affect the least significant digit in the decimal representation. You have to store the entire decimal representation to transform the bit string.

If you can't find a long decimal data class / library for your language, you can construct it yourself, it's not hard. Just store enough decimal digits, e.g. as a list, and do the math. You only need addition for this task, so it's extra easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use an arbitrary precision numeric (bignum) library, like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

GMP has a "[gmp_scanf](http://gmplib.org/manual-4.3.2/Formatted-Input-Strings.html#Formatted-Input-Strings)" function that does just what you are asking for.

Comment: "(...) supposing (...) that you can't convert it to an integer first (...)"

Comment: @Miguel - A good bignum lib should have utilities for that. Eg: http://gmplib.org/manual-4.3.2/Formatted-Input-Strings.html#Formatted-Input-Strings

Comment: You can't convert it to a _machine_ integer, but arbitrary precision bignums are not machine integers (and need not be integers, btw).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you do not have an arbitrary precision math package at your disposal, but you do have
a set of basic string manipulation routines, you could do the following:

Construct a list of powers of 2 then deconstruct the binary string in reverse
order one bit at a time by adding in the appropriate power of 2 for every '1' bit in the string.

The only arbitrary precision arithmetic function you need to do this is addition, and this is fairly
easy to implement using long-hand arithmetic.

Suppose you did implement an arbitrary arithmetic add function called:
`ADD` taking 2 strings containing decimal numbers as input and returning the decimal sum
as a string. Something like:

```
  SumString = ADD(DecimalString1, DecimalString2)
```

`SumString` is a string of decimal digits representing the sum of `DecimalString1` and `DecimalString2`.

Step1: Construct a powers of 2 list as follows:

```
  BitString is string           /* String of '1' and '0' values... */
  BitString = '111001101001110100100(...)1001001111011100100' /* or whatever... */

  PowerOf2 is array of string  /* Array of strings containing powers of 2 */
  PowerOf2[1] = '1'            /* 2**0 to get things started... */
  /* Build as many powers of 2 as there are 'bits' in the input string */   
  for i from 2 to length(BitString) by +1  
    PowerOf2[i] = ADD(PowerOf2[i-1], PowerOf2[i-1])  
    end
```

Note: Above assumes arrays/strings are 1 based (as opposed to zero based).

Step 2: Deconstruct the BitString accumulating the sum as you go:

```
  DecimalValue is string        /* Decimal value of BitString */
  BitString is string           /* Your input set of bits as a string... */
  ReverseBitString is string    /* Reversed input */

  DecimalValue = ''             /* Result */  
  BitString = '111001101001110100100(...)1001001111011100100' /* or whatever... */  
  ReverseBitString = reverse(BitString) /* Reverse so we process lsb to msb */  

  for i from 1 to length(ReverseBitString) by +1  
     if substr(ReverseBitString, i, 1) == '1' then  /* Bit at position i */  
        DecimalValue = ADD(DecimalValue, PowerOf2[i])  
        end   
     end    

  if DecimalValue = '' then DecimalValue = '0' /* bit string was all zero */   
  Display DecimalValue /* This is the result */
```

How to build an arbitrary precision `ADD` function? It goes something like:

```
  function ADD (DecVal1 is string, DecVal2 is string) return string  
     SumVal is string   
     Rev1 is string  
     Rev2 is string      
     DigitSum is integer
     CarryDigit is integer

     SumVal = ''               /* Result so far... */
     Rev1 = reverse(DecVal1)   /* Reverse digit order */
     Rev2 = reverse(DecVal2)   /* Reverse digit order */

     /* Pad shorter reversed sting with trailing zeros... */
     if length(Rev1) > length(Rev2) then
        Rev2 = concat(Rev2, copies(length(Rev1) - length(Rev2), '0')
        end
     else
        Rev1 = concat(Rev1, copies(length(Rev2) - length(Rev1), '0')
        end

     /* Sum by digit position, least to most significant */
     CarryDigit = 0    
     for i from 1 to length(Rev1) by + 1
        DigitSum = CtoI(substr(Rev1, i, 1)) + CtoI(substr(Rev2, i, 1)) + CarryDigit
        if DigitSum > 9 then
           DigitSum = DigitSum - 10
           CarryDigit = 1
           end
        else
           CarryDigit = 0
           end 

        SumVal = concat(ItoC(DigitSum), SumVal)
        end

      if CarryDigit > 0 then
        SumVal = concat(ItoC(CarryDigit), SumVal)
        end

      return SumVal
```

Assumed built in string functions:

- reverse(String): Returns the string in reverse order
- length(String): Returns length of a given string
- concat(String, String): Returns concatenation of two strings
- substr(String, start, length): Returns substring of string from start for length characters (1 based)
- CtoI(String): Returns decimal integer value of given character (eg. '1' = 1, '2' = 2, ...)
- ItoC(Integer): Returns decimal character representation of integer (eg. 1 = '1', 2 = '2', ...)
- copies(count, string): Returns count concatinated copies of string

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

```
void toBCD1( char *p ) {
    const int decSize = 120; // Arbitrary limit of 10^119.
    static binByte decDgt[ decSize ]; // decimal digits as binary 'nibbles'.
    int curPow10 = 0;

    memset( decDgt, 0, sizeof(decDgt) );

    for( char *cp = p; *cp; cp++ ) {

        for( int ii = curPow10; ii >= 0; ii-- ) {
            if( decDgt[ ii ] >= 5 ) // Algorithm step
                decDgt[ ii ] += 3;

            decDgt[ ii ] <<= 1;

            if( decDgt[ ii ] & 0x10 ) { // Carry high bit?
                decDgt[ ii + 1 ] |= 0x1;
                if( ii == curPow10 ) // new power of 10?
                    curPow10++;
                decDgt[ ii ] &= 0xF; // dealing in 'nibbles'
            }
        }
        decDgt[ 0 ] |= ( *cp == '1' ); // truth value 0 or 1
    }
    for( int ii = curPow10; ii >= 0; ii-- )
        putchar( decDgt[ ii ] + '0' );
    putchar( '\n' );
}

void demo_toBCD( void ) {
    char *bp =  "11100110"
                "10011101"
                "00100100"
                "10011110"
                "11100100"
                "01001001"
                "11101110"
                "01000100"
                "10011110"
                "11100100";
    toBCD1( bp );
}
```