# Displaying 1024 bit binary number in base 10 c++

Tags: c++, random

I'll try explaining my problem to the best of my ability. To start off, here's my code for a program I wrote that generates an array of n length, where each element is either a 1 or a 0. The next method takes in an array made from the first method and formats it into a binary number that can be printed to the console.

```
#include "bigNum.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

short* genArr(int bits)
{
        static short *numArr = new short[bits];
        srand(time(0));
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i<bits; i++) {
                numArr[i] = rand() % 2;
        }
        return numArr;
}

void formatNum(short arr[], int size) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i<size; ++i) {
                std::cout<<arr[i];
        }
        std::cout<<"\n";
}
```

The main reason why I created this program is to generate large random numbers to the order of 1024 bits and beyond. I don't think a simple binary to int conversion will work because the size of my binary number is not constant, and it can clearly be larger than 64 bits.

For example, if I generate a 1024 bit binary number, it prints to the console:

```
./test 1024
00100110110011111111000111011111001001010001110111011001100010110010110010111000101101011011000100101101110110110100001000110100110110000011010000000101110110101010011010                     01101111010001000100100100011001111110010110011101101110111011111100101110000110000011001110101011010101101110000001000111101101000010011100000010010000110001111111010110                         11101001111110011100000110111010100001010101010101101110101000111101001011110000100010010111100000000110001100110011010000100000001110100011000000001010000100111000010111                         00000000101001000100010001100000000101111011001011011111001001011000111001101000011100000100101001001001101001000110110110100101011111001100100110001010100111000111101011                         00110010000111111101101010000011000001001110010100111010001000101111010001010000111011011101011110010010001000111011100010110101110110010100110111011011110101010011011001                         10011101001010111101000100011100101011101000110000001001000110100001011101010010011111001011011010011111110110011111011100001011010101110111111100001111100101000010000001
```

EDIT: sorry, I can't remove the long tabs. I think it was due to a copy/paste formatting error.

What I want to do is to convert this long binary number into a string that displays the base 10 representation of this. I couldn't find similar problems online, so I'm resorting to posting a question here. I hope I described my problem thoroughly.

Comment: I assume you either didn't want to use [`_ExtInt(1024)`](http://blog.llvm.org/2020/04/the-new-clang-extint-feature-provides.html), or aren't using clang.

Comment: Remember that in C++ `std::vector` exists and it helps manage memory better than this leaky code. You could also implement your own template class that has an arbitrary bit length as well.

Comment: 2^1024 is something like 10^30, so i think that whatever method will fail..

Comment: @tadman as i was creating my program, i just learned about std::vector, and will give it a try. Also, when you said implement a template class, is that not the same as creating a header file with the templates for the two methods?

Comment: A template class is a more advanced C++ technique where you can change the structure dynamically according to arguments. If you're learning C++ I'd encourage you to write this as a class first which has a fixed bit length (e.g. 1024 or something) and then later make it more flexible. This procedural style you have here is really missing the point of what C++ can do for you, *especially* when it comes to constructors and destructors for ensuring allocations are properly cleaned up.

Comment: check this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246976/binary-string-to-decimal-string

Comment: The point here is if you call `new[]` you're responsible for calling `delete[]` somewhere else in your code to free that resource.

Comment: You should start by writing a simple function that takes a string of binary digits, and returns the decimal number as a string or as a "BigNum".  All of these things you're doing with `srand`, `new[]` are totally irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yup! that's my question! I was simply providing background context, and I knew that I really didn't have to do that. I could have phrased my question exactly in one sentence: "how to convert binary string to decimal." But now, I've learned a few more concepts that other people pointed out, all because I provided additional code. Thanks for restating my problem.

Comment: I think it would be easier if you used a big number class, and do the base 2 to base 10 conversion using that class.  I mean you are using 1024 bit numbers, and most, if not every compiler out there does not have native 1024 bit numbers.  There are a few big number libraries that are available.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into that as well.

Comment: Why do you want to see the base 10 representation? If it is just along the lines of being more compact than the binary representation, I'd advise you to consider the base 16 (hexadecimal) representation instead. The hexadecimal representation is much easier to produce than decimal in your case, is a bit more compact than decimal, and is commonly used by (hence is familiar to many) programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need support from a big integer library. But just a tiny part of it. Such a small part that we can implement it together.

First thing, let's change a bit your code to make it manageable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

std::vector<short> genArr(int bits)
{
    std::vector<short> numArr(bits);
    srand(time(0));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<bits; i++) 
    {
        numArr[i] = rand() % 2;
    }
    return numArr;
}

void formatNum(std::vector<short> arr)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<arr.size(); ++i) 
    {
        std::cout<<arr[i];
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
}
```

Pretty much the same as before, just using vectors. Then, you can simply implement very high-level logic, assuming you have a big int library:

```
void formatNumDec(std::vector<short> arr)
{
    LargeNum n;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        n = n * 2;
        if (arr[i])
        {
            ++n;
        }
    }
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

All we did was: for each digit, multiply our current value by 2, then add zero or one, depending on the next bit.

We relied on:

- assignment operator
- increment operator
- star operator (for multiply)

Let's use this:

```
class LargeNum
{
public:
    int base;
    std::vector<int> digits;
```

we get the assignment operator by default. Let's throw in a constructor:

```
    LargeNum():base(10) {}
```

Let's implement increment by adding one to the last digit and carrying it over. This only works for small value, but `1` is a small value.

```
    LargeNum& operator++()
    {
        int pos = 0;
        bool carry = false;
        do
        {
            carry = false;
            if (pos >= digits.size())
            {
                digits.push_back(0);
            }
            digits[pos]++;
            if (digits[pos] == base)
            {
                digits[pos] = 0;
                carry = true;
            }
        }
        while(carry);

        return *this;
    }
```

And the last bit we need is multiplication by 2. Let's implement multiplication by any small value (say 1 to 10) by multiplying each digit and carrying over:

```
    LargeNum& operator*(int mult)
    {
        int carry = 0;
        for(int pos = 0; pos < digits.size(); pos++)
        {
            digits[pos] = digits[pos] * mult + carry;
            carry = digits[pos] / 10;
            digits[pos] %= 10;
        }
        if (carry)
        {
            digits.push_back(carry);
        }

        return *this;
    }
};
```

That gives us a solution using a big integer lib that works for very limited cases. But enough for your use case. If we test it:

```
int main()
{
    auto num = genArr(13);
    formatNum(num);
    formatNumDec(num);
}
```

We get:

```
1100011100011
6371(10)
```

or, with larger values:

```
1101110010011010101101000111001011011010010001110000101101011000011111001011010101011111001010111011111001110100110110111101000101001111000000110000000111111000010110101100110100111001101101101111010011001100111011001101110000100010110010010101111100101110000101000110111101000101001100001110001010111110101001111101111100010110011111111111010100010110000010001000001001000010111010101100111000001000000100101010111111110100110101001111101100000100001000010011111011011100111101011011111000001111001001011011010111101101000101000101100111001000111100010001001010101110101001110001110000011101000001010010001110011110100000011111100011001010111111101010100011010000011100100110001001111110010011110001011111101111001010000000101000010100010000110101000111100001001111011110111111000100100010000011111000001111110001111011011000100101111101111111100011111001101100001011100111111011011010111111001100001110011100101001101011111011101000110001110010000010010111110101001111111111100010000110011111010010011
73868569780955456124228707899822160955495544892638015310179220061186136753214543146234756723216826639708631800432713243173835264416984333326210886331495933792989604726456910722925688428304932474264611559781633323648147423739204040611247483503242836728251464923462071095422092950093094774327508960755347(10)
```

I did not worry about which direction (from smallest or largest digit you were treating your binary. Please adjust accordingly).

Comment: Wow! This answer was very detailed and gave me a lot of insight about the things I could do in my code. Is there any place where you got this algorithm from? If so, I'd like to read more about it so I have a better understanding. Marking this as the helpful answer.

Comment: You can look at some blogs that explain it in pseudo-code, like https://www.google.com/amp/s/silentmatt.com/blog/2011/10/how-bigintegers-work/amp/

Comment: @jamit comment is also a good one. Using base 16, or even 256 or 65536 will simplify many things. Memory density, making some operations simpler and faster, allowing the use of binary masks and shifts... Remember: a large integer library is a big project. But also a good exercise and learning occasion.